# Xamarin Forms- How to get the current timer status and continue running after the app is closed and reopened?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

UPDATE: I have formulated the question more precisely

I have programmed an app in Xamarin form (Android) that has a timer and I have programmed everything in MainPage.cs class. Everything works correctly until now only when I close the app(sending to background) and open it again. The problem is that when I open the app again then the timer no longer runs but it simply displays the remaining time at the moment of opening the app.The timer is not running. I have read that Xamarin Forms calls the OnSleep, OnResume method in this case and you should program there that the timer is retrieved correctly again and continues to run. I have little experience with it and could not find anything good after long research. Who knows how the timer can be retrieved and run again after opening. Thank you very much

Here is my Methode in MainPage for the timer

```
public void StartCountdown()
{    
 CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
 CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;

 if (cancel == true)
 {
     tokenSource.Cancel();
 }

 task = Task.Run(async () =>
{
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
        {
            restTime -= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            if (cancel == true)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (restTime == zero)
            {
                StartDownload();
                return false; 
             }
            else
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    ActivateElements(false);
                });

                return true;                       
             }
        });
    
}, token);
}
```

How can I implement the timer method in App.cs and is it necessary at all ?

```
public partial class App : Application
{

    public App()
    {
   
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
       
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: stop or pause the timer in OnSleep.  Restart it in OnResume.  What specifically don't you understand how to do?  Since you haven't posted any of your code it's difficult to get you a specific example.

Comment: Thank you Jason. How can i use the StartCountdown - Methode in App.cs and in OnResume - Methode

Comment: @Yves You will need to implement an Android Foreground Service if you wish to have a process continue in the background: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services

Comment: Thank you SushiHangover. I have implemented the foreground service. The problem is when I open the app after closed it. Than the timer ist not running. It shows only the remaining time every time when I open the app

Comment: It's not really clear if you want your timer to continue running when the App is paused?  Or to only run when MainPage is active?  And I suggest you use System.Timers instead of Device.

Comment: @Jason - The Problem is only when the app is reopening and the timer is not running. How can i use a Methode from MainPage in OnResume Methode ? Thank you

Comment: create public methods on your MainPage.  Call them from your App class using the MainPage reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create public methods in your page to pause/resume the timer, then in your App class

```
protected override void OnSleep()
{
   ((MainPage)MainPage).SomePublicMethodToPauseTimer();
}

protected override void OnResume()
{
   ((MainPage)MainPage).SomePublicMethodToResumeTimer();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jason. I think this will be the right direction :)